# Stuck when Installing R in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, r

I am installing R in Ubuntu 16.04.3
I did as this [website](http://www.datascienceriot.com//r/install-ubuntu16/) tells, but I got stuck here, figure below,
any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: How long has it been stuck there ? It seems to be a downloading issue.

Comment: Till now, it has been about an hour

Comment: You can try to reset the download and then try again : CTRL+C to stop then  `sudo apt-get clean`to clean your local repo and then try the command again `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev` (assuming this is the command you tried, since you didn't say it in your post)

Comment: Amazing! I tried the command as you told and it is installed, and I also installed Rstudio-server, but when I opened Rstudio server, it uses old version R, any suggestion?

Comment: You can try the "Linux" part of : https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

Comment: OK... it turns out I did not manage to update/install newest version R, when I type sudo apt-get update, I am still get stuck; But I think I did install r-base r-base-dev, due to command sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev